# Regular Expression

Tags: jmeter

Writing regular expression for below code

```
<select name="fromPort" class="form-inline">
        <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
        <option value="Philadelphia">Philadelphia</option>
        <option value="Boston">Boston</option>
        <option value="Portland">Portland</option>
        <option value="San Diego">San Diego</option>
        <option value="Mexico City">Mexico City</option>
        <option value="São Paolo">São Paolo</option>
    </select>
    <p>
    <h2>Choose your destination city:</h2>
    <select name="toPort" class="form-inline">
        <option value="Buenos Aires">Buenos Aires</option>
        <option value="Rome">Rome</option>
        <option value="London">London</option>
        <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
        <option value="Dublin">Dublin</option>
        <option value="Cairo">Cairo</option>
    </select>
```

I am using  but it is capturing all the drop-down values from different drop-down list. I need values to be separated by fields

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that [using Regular Expressions for extracting values from HTML responses might not be the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) as:

- Regular expressions would be hard to create and maintain
- Regular expressions will be very sensitive to markup change, i.e. new line or attribute order will run your test

I would recommend going for [CSS/JQuery Extractor instead](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter)

1. Add CSS/JQuery Extractor as a child of the request
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `from`
   - CSS/JQuery expression: `select[name=fromPort] > option`
   - Attribute: `value`
   - Match No. `-1`
3. It will generate the following matches:

   [image: JMeter CSS/JQuery Extractor Matches]
4. Resulting in the next [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

   [image: JMeter CSS Jquery Extractor Generated Variables]
5. Now you will be able to refer them as:

   - `${from_1}` - will result in `Paris`
   - `${from_2}` - will return `Philadelphia`
   - etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help sir.
Yes it does work. CaN we use it for below as well? <input type="hidden" value="43" name="flight"> <input type="hidden" value="472.56" name="price"> <input type="hidden" value="Virgin America" name="airline">